# Url is not loading on android webview for Mote(Kitkat)

Tags: android, webview, android-4.4-kitkat

My site URL(https://www.m.monkvyasa.com/) is not loading on a web view in my Motoe phone(which runs kitkat OS). The URL created in react js and which is perfectly open in chrome and other browsers, but while I tried to load this URL through web view it show a loading bar only, contents are not loading after that. The problem is observed only in Moto phone, for other devices it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,Check if you can load a real website like Google or something, if not there is something wrong with your webview or permissions.
Secondly,inspect the webview by debug the app with the chrome inspect tool, it will tell you if there are any errors.
You can post the console errors and I would try to help if you want

Comment: It shows an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getItem' of null " and don't know from where it raises

Comment: @ShantoGeorge please always post such findings (such as this log message) when posting the question.